# What test setup to use for an angular/ionic app compiled with capacitor, running in a web view?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, ionic-framework, webview, capacitor

I have an app built on angular and ionic, compiled with capacitor to Android.
I would like to automatically test the android build of the app.
I tried appium and selenium. I listed all the elements in the app, but only the native Android elements show up. The controls I am interested in are apparently all within a web view. How can I click on the button with id 'login_button' inside that webView using selenium or other test automation tool?

My test class looks like this:

```
package com.kodekonveyor.integrationtests;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class FirstAndroidTest {
    public static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait                wait;
    
    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("app", "target/app-debug.apk");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.kodekonveyor.angulartest");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.kodekonveyor.angulartest.MainActivity");
        
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, IntegrationtestsConstants.WAIT_TIME);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void basicTest() throws InterruptedException {
        //Click and pass Splash
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add("------------------------------->");
        elements.forEach(
                (WebElement foo) -> {
                    result.add("tagname:"+foo.getTagName());
                    result.add("class:"+foo.getAttribute("class"));
                    result.add("contentDescription:"+foo.getAttribute("contentDescription"));
                    }
                );
        result.add("-------------------------------<");
        result.forEach(
                (String line) ->
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                });
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    public static void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
------------------------------->
tagname:null
class:android.widget.FrameLayout
contentDescription:null
tagname:null
class:android.widget.LinearLayout
contentDescription:null
tagname:null
class:android.widget.FrameLayout
contentDescription:null
tagname:null
class:android.widget.LinearLayout
contentDescription:null
tagname:null
class:android.widget.FrameLayout
contentDescription:null
tagname:null
class:android.view.ViewGroup
contentDescription:null
tagname:null
class:android.webkit.WebView
contentDescription:null
-------------------------------<
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/

About chromedriver: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/

I ended up just using `appium --chromedriver-executable <path>`

Chromedriver is quite picky about versions. The version of chromedriver on the host should be the same as the one in the emulator. Even if chrome://inspect will work, appium will not.

The working test:

```
    @Test
    public void basicTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        String webcontext = null;
        for (String contextName : contextNames) {
            System.out.println(contextName);
            if(contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
                webcontext = contextName;
            }
        }
        if(null == webcontext)
            fail("no web context found");
        driver.context(webcontext);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("login_button"))).click();
```